# Return Column name in case statement but no table involved

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi Can anyone help with the problem below, I have a stored procedure which depending on the month and date, depends on which image is returned. I have found plenty of examples of how to solve this when the data is in a table, but no solutions on how I'm doing it.

The reason why I'm doing it this way is because it will be easier to modify the sql in the procedure than having to change and upload the new code to the website.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth int
SET @CurrentMonth = ( MONTH(GETDATE()))

DECLARE @CurrentDate int
SET @CurrentDate = ( Day(GETDATE()))

--DECLARE @Url varchar(100)
--SET @URL = ''


    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
          --Set image for xmas
          CASE WHEN @CurrentMonth = 12 AND @CurrentDate = 25
             THEN (SELECT 'imagetest.png' AS URL)
          --Set for easter
           WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
             THEN (SELECT 'imagetest2.png' AS url)
          --Keep setting images for events
          WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
             THEN (SELECT 'imagetest3.png' AS url)
          --If no match, return default image
          ELSE (SELECT 'logo.png' AS url)
       END

      -- return @URL
    END
```

The sp executes ok, but the column is (No Column Name) when what I want is url as the column  name.

Any help from someone more experienced would be appreciated.

I'm using SQL2008R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the inner `SELECT`s:

```
SELECT
      --Set image for xmas
      CASE WHEN @CurrentMonth = 12 AND @CurrentDate = 25
         THEN 'imagetest.png'
      --Set for easter
       WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN 'imagetest2.png'
      --Keep setting images for events
      WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN 'imagetest3.png'
      --If no match, return default image
      ELSE  'logo.png' 
   END AS url
```

BTW, March 19th will NEVER be an Easter Sunday.  March 22 is the earliest possible [Easter date](http://www.smart.net/~mmontes/freq3.html)

Comment: Hi D Stanley I know, I was just putting any date in to check if it works :)

Comment: D Stanley I need to wait 3 mins before I can award answer, funny how something look so easy when you see the answer, I was rattling my brain tying to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

The `AS URL` needs to be at the end of your case statement

```
CASE
...
END AS URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column alias to the case statement. Case statements are an if/then proposition and SQL server does not assign a name based on the column(s) tested. You are free to name them yourself.

```
DECLARE @CurrentMonth int
SET @CurrentMonth = ( MONTH(GETDATE()))

DECLARE @CurrentDate int
SET @CurrentDate = ( Day(GETDATE()))

--DECLARE @Url varchar(100)
--SET @URL = ''


SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT
      --Set image for xmas
      CASE WHEN @CurrentMonth = 12 AND @CurrentDate = 25
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest.png' AS URL)
      --Set for easter
       WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest2.png' AS url)
      --Keep setting images for events
      WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest3.png' AS url)
      --If no match, return default image
      ELSE (SELECT 'logo.png' AS url)
   END as MyURL --edit to your liking

  -- return @URL
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your column name after your case statement:

```
SELECT
  --Set image for xmas
      CASE WHEN @CurrentMonth = 12 AND @CurrentDate = 25
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest.png' AS URL)
      --Set for easter
       WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest2.png' AS url)
      --Keep setting images for events
      WHEN @CurrentMonth = 3 AND @CurrentDate = 19
         THEN (SELECT 'imagetest3.png' AS url)
      --If no match, return default image
      ELSE (SELECT 'logo.png' AS url)
   END AS url
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different way that you can do that, which might be easier to maintain:

```
select top 1 Url from (
  select Mon = null, Dat = null, Url = 'logo.png' union all
  select 12, 25, 'imagetest.png' union all
  select 3, 19, 'imagetest2.png' union all
  select 3, 19, 'imagetest3.png'
) x
where (Mon = @CurrentMonth and Dat = @CurrentDate) or (Mon is null)
order by Mon desc
```